# Data studio - Google search console ranking positions chart by month

Tags: looker-studio, google-search-console

In G data studio, I'm trying to create a chart that shows search queries ranked in the first position, third position, top ten and >10 by month. I've tried this
CASE
WHEN Average position < 2 THEN "Top 1"
WHEN Average position <= 3 THEN "Top 3"
WHEN Average position <= 10 THEN "Top 10"
WHEN Average position <= 20 THEN "Top 20"
Else "Other"
END
with the date (month date time series) as the dimensions and just got a solid block.

I've tried creating a chart with dims = date, metric = search query and filter by top position (to at least get one to work) and no luck.

I've tried with and without searchmetrics hooked up to data studio and I can't get it to work. In case it's a Google Search Console url vs site data issue, I've blended the 2 (one using the average data and the second using the search query (with the date as the connector) and it doesn't work.

Has anyone had any success in creating a monthly chart that shows keyword ranking positions?

Comment: Is it a time chart with the break down dimension beeing your CASE WHEN ... formula? Please add a screen shot of your configuration and some more details. A solid block could be beacuse there are too many break down dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happens to me, I think you have to set the configuration by console in data studio, since a position has commas for example top 3> = 1 & <= 3, and the positions that are shown in the average are 1 , 05, 2.67 etc ... and these numbers are not taken.